# Adding path for icpc in bashrc?

Tags: linux, bash, icc

Every time I have to run icpc I have to type `icpc -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/`

How to include this is `bashrc` file so I have to just type icpc ?

Comment: Type `help alias` in your shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the path to the `C_INCLUDE` variable.

```
export C_INCLUDE="$C_INCLUDE:/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/"
```

The preceding line should go into your `.bash_profile` file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [bash aliases](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/aliases.html):

```
alias icpc="icpc -I /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/"
```

Answer (score 0):

as an alternative to an alias, you can define a function in your .bashrc:
See [Bash functions](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/functions.html)

```
icpc ()
{
   icpc -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/ 
}
```

The benefit of using a function is that you can have parameters (well, you can have parameters to an alias as well as long as the parameter is the last one on the line).

The function refers to passed arguments by position (as if they were positional parameters), that is, $1, $2, and so forth.

In order to call the function with arguments, change it to:

```
icpc ()
{
   icpc -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/ "$@"
}
```

In that way you can use

```
$ ipc some_argument
```

and have it executed as

```
icpc -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/ some_argument
```

Comment: You should probably add `"$@"` at the end to pass on any arguments to icpc.